# MVC 4 DropDownListFor Set Selected Item Based on Text

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

Normally when I use the DropDownListFor helper I'm selecting which item is selected based on an ID (int), but now I have a situation where I need to display which item is selected based on the text (string) and not an ID. In the controller the model is being set correctly to the value that I want with this property:

```
model.Title
```

An example title would be "Front Office". I have the following code in my Controller:

```
ViewBag.Titles = new SelectList(jobTitles, "Name", "Name");
```

and on the view I have this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Title, ViewBag.Titles as SelectList)
```

The DropDownList is populating correctly with all the expected job titles, it just isn't selecting the correct job title based on **model.Title**.  What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

There seems to be something else potentially going wrong in my code, so I'm putting all of it here to see if I'm doing something wrong.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        StaffMember staffmember = StaffMember.SelectByID(id); // gets staff member from db

        ViewBag.Titles = new SelectList(JobTitle.SelectAll(), "Name", "Name", staffmember.Title); // JobTitle.SelectAll() returns List<JobTitle>

        StaffEditModel model = new StaffEditModel();
        model.ID = staffmember.ID;
        model.ClientID = staffmember.ClientID;
        model.FirstName = staffmember.FirstName;
        model.MiddleInitial = staffmember.MiddleInitial;
        model.LastName = staffmember.LastName;
        model.Title = staffmember.Title;
        model.Phone = staffmember.Phone;
        model.Email = staffmember.Email;
        model.Birthday = staffmember.Birthday;
        model.HireDate = staffmember.HireDate;
        model.Biography = staffmember.Biography;

        if (staffmember == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Model:

```
public class StaffEditModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int ClientID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Middle Initial")]
    public string MiddleInitial { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; } // this is the property I'm trying to show in DropDown

    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public string Birthday { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Hire Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public string HireDate { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(14)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Biography { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Title, new SelectList(ViewBag.Titles,"Value","Text", Model.Title))
```

Comment: Does your `JobTitle.SelectAll()` returns `List<string>`? Or another type of object?

Answer (score 3):

This should work.
You can pass `ViewBag.Titles` as `List<SelectListItem>` from controller

```
var jobList = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach (var job in jobTitles)
{
    var item = new SelectListItem();
    item.Value = job.PropertyName; //the property you want to display i.e. Title
    item.Text = job.PropertyName;
    jobList.Add(item);
}
ViewBag.Title = jobList;
```

and then in the view,

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Title, new SelectList(ViewBag.Titles,"Value","Text", Model.Title))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I gave this a shot and am passing in a `List<SelectListItem>` and using the following code in the View:   `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Title, new SelectList(ViewBag.Titles, "Text", "Text", Model.Title))`  but getting the same results as I was before where it doesn't select the item I'm looking for. For the dropdown the **value** and the **text** are the same.

Comment: I have modified the code and it's working for me. Check it out.

Comment: thanks again. There must be something else going on in my code because even your updated code isn't working for me. I've done this many times before, but for some reason this one is the only one I've really struggled with. I'm going to update my question with my complete code to see if there is anything I'm doing incorrectly.  Thanks again for all your help!  I have no doubt your code is right and working, I'm just thinking there is something else going on.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to the party on this, but I had a similar problem and thought I would add what I've found.

I haven't figured out the why yet - I'm still researching (that's how I ended up here) - but I think it has something to do with the fact that you're using the word *Title*

I've got the exact same scenario and as soon as I changed my model to *CustomerTitle* instead of *Title* things worked as expected.

Initial thoughts are that the model binder is finding *Title* somewhere else in the DOM and getting tripped up.  Complete speculation.  If I have more time I'll keep digging for the why

Comment: I got this exact situation too -  so I change mine to CustomerTitle and it worked... I'd be interested to know why this happens if anyone knows...